# strtok returns zero with length one string

Tags: c, csv, gcc

I'm trying to parse a CSV to a double matrix. The string could look like so `"1,5\n6,4\n,4.2,6.8\0"`.

The variables are declared outside of the loop as follows:

```
double csv [MAX_SIZE, MAX_SIZE]; //initialized to a size greater then the data of the csv to parse.
char line [LINE_CAP]; //assigned per line via fgets. e.g. "1,5\n6,4\n,4.2,6.8\0"
char* token; //assigned to line segment separated per delim. e.g. 1\0
```

Here is the code snipped:

```
for (int l_cols = 0; (token = strtok(lnptr, ",")) != NULL; l_cols++) { //foreach token in line
   lnptr = NULL;
   if (l_cols > cols) {
      cols = l_cols;
   }
   double d = strtod(token, NULL);
   printf("csv[%d,%d] = '%s'", rows, cols, token);
   csv[rows][cols] = d; //convert the trimmed token to double and assign it to the csv
   printf(", converted %d, assigned %d\n", d, csv[rows][cols]);
}
```

Now my problem is that the second printf always return zero for the values, not 1 or 5 respectively. Example output:

```
[...]
A[2,3] = '1', converted 0, assigned 0
A[2,3] = '5', converted 0, assigned 0
[...]
```

The problem probably lies with the `strtok` as everything before and after looks good. Why does `strtok` return zero even though the string entered is a valid number, and can I fix that?

Comment: `double csv [MAX_SIZE, MAX_SIZE];` is bad syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to print `double` variables with the `%d` format specified.  That is [undefined behavior per the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9):

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

This code is wrong:

```
printf(", converted %d, assigned %d\n", d, csv[rows][cols]);
```

because

```
double csv [MAX_SIZE, MAX_SIZE];
```

and

```
double d = strtod(token, NULL);
```

This would be better:

```
printf(", converted %f, assigned %f\n", d, csv[rows][cols]);
```

Comment: That would explain why it doesn't show anything. You solved it, the program works fine now. Well now I feel stupid, but thanks for noticing!

Comment: @RenéCarannante Being unable to see the bugs in your own code is pretty common - you write what you think is correct code, and when it doesn't work you still look at the code with the same assumptions you had when you wrote it.  All too many times I've had to leave for the day unable to solve a problem, and when I see my code the next morning the problem is obvious.  Asking another programmer, "Could you look at this?" is a pretty common debugging technique.